# Run sampling process for certain amount of time and return value in Java

Tags: java, timeout, process-control

I have a Java method that does sampling.  That is, it does something like this:

```
TIME = 60 /* seconds */

startTime = now();
count = 0;
while (now() - startTime < TIME) {
    sample = createRandomSample();
    if (satisfiesSomeConditions(sample)) {
       count++;
    }
}

return count;
```

Now, usually, createRandomSample() and satisfiesSomeConditions(sample) run pretty fast (as in a second or less), so this code works well.

However, once in a while, one of these functions might take a long time to run.  How can I control this sampling process to run not much longer than requested by TIME.  I don't mind if it runs, say, 10% longer than TIME, but I don't want it running for some arbitrarily long amount of time over TIME.

An ExecutorService seems too harsh.

It's more like we want to run the sampling on a separate thread and then gently tell that thread to stop sampling and give whatever results it currently has.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `FutureTask`. Something like this:

```
FutureTask<Void> futureTask = new FutureTask<Void>(new Callable<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        doStuff();
        return null;
    }
    });
futureTask.run();
futureTask.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //handle exceptions
```

The `get()` method terminates when the callable is done. If that happens before the timeout, everything is fine. If not, it throws a `TimeoutException` which you have to catch in this case.